# How to extend TileLayer component in react-leaflet v3?

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to extend the TileLayer component in 'react-leaflet' v3. It is necessary to override this function to provide custom tile URL naming scheme.
An example of what I need, written in basic leaflet:

```
function initMap() {
    L.TileLayer.WebGis = L.TileLayer.extend({

        initialize: function (url, options) {
            options = L.setOptions(this, options);
            if (options.detectRetina && L.Browser.retina && options.maxZoom > 0) {
                options.tileSize = Math.floor(options.tileSize / 2);
                options.zoomOffset++;
                if (options.minZoom > 0) {
                    options.minZoom--;
                }
                this.options.maxZoom--;
            }
            if (options.bounds) {
                options.bounds = L.latLngBounds(options.bounds);
            }
            this._url = url + "/gis_render/{x}_{y}_{z}/" + options.userId + "/tile.png";
            var subdomains = this.options.subdomains;
            if (typeof subdomains === 'string') {
                this.options.subdomains = subdomains.split('');
            }
        },

        getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {
            return L.Util.template(this._url, L.extend({
                s: this._getSubdomain(tilePoint),
                z: 17 - this._map._zoom,
                x: tilePoint.x,
                y: tilePoint.y
            }, this.options));
        }
    });

    L.tileLayer.webGis = function (url, options) {
        return new L.TileLayer.WebGis(url, options);
    };

    // create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
    var map = L.map('map').setView([53.9, 27.55], 10);

    // add an Gurtam Maps tile layer
    L.tileLayer.webGis(wialon.core.Session.getInstance().getBaseGisUrl('render'), {
        attribution: 'Gurtam Maps',
        minZoom: 4,
        userId: wialon.core.Session.getInstance().getCurrUser().getId()
    }).addTo(map);

}
```

If I just write a url of Gurtam maps to a 'url' prop of TileLayer component, then my map incorrectly displayed (zoom and tile errors).

I can't figure out what to use for the correct display:

1. Use 'useRef' hook to get the current TileLayer instance and extend it.
2. Use some hook (maybe createElementHook) from package 'react-leaflet/core' and create my own custom component
3. Or something else

I would be grateful for any explanations.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using `react-leaflet` and `typescript`: I recreated the [kitten example from leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html) in LeafletJS style and typescript based on [Seth Lutske's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65713838/4295853).

Javascript:

```js
import L from "leaflet";
import { createLayerComponent } from "@react-leaflet/core";

// @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65713838/4295853
// @ts-ignore
L.TileLayer.Kitten = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(coords: L.Coords) {
        var i = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 4 );
        return "https://placekitten.com/256/256?image=" + i;
    },
    getAttribution: function() {
        return "<a href='https://placekitten.com/attribution.html'>PlaceKitten</a>"
    }
});

// @ts-ignore
L.tileLayer.kitten = function() {
    // @ts-ignore
    return new L.TileLayer.Kitten();
}

// @ts-ignore
const createKittenLayer = (props, context) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const instance = L.tileLayer.kitten(props.url, {...props});
    return {instance, context};
}

// @ts-ignore
const updateKittenLayer = (instance, props, prevProps) => {
    if (prevProps.url !== props.url) {
        if (instance.setUrl) instance.setUrl(props.url)
    }

    if (prevProps.userId !== props.userId) {
        if (instance.setUserId) instance.setUserId(props.userId)
    }
}

const KittenLayer = createLayerComponent(createKittenLayer, updateKittenLayer);
export default KittenLayer;
```

Typescript (practical but not leaflet convention see in [this SO answer's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692385/4295853)):

```js
import L, { Coords, DoneCallback, GridLayer } from "leaflet";
import {createLayerComponent, LayerProps } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface KittenProps extends LayerProps {
    userId: string,
    children?: ReactNode // PropsWithChildren is not exported by @react-leaflet/core
}

class Kitten extends L.TileLayer {

    getTileUrl(coords: L.Coords) {
        var i = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 4 );
        return "https://placekitten.com/256/256?image=" + i;
    }

    getAttribution() {
        return "<a href='https://placekitten.com/attribution.html'>PlaceKitten</a>"
    }

}

const createKittenLayer = (props: KittenProps, context:any) => {
    const instance = new Kitten("placeholder", {...props});
    return {instance, context};
}

const updateKittenLayer = (instance: any, props: KittenProps, prevProps: KittenProps) => {
      if (prevProps.userId !== props.userId) {
        if (instance.setUserId) instance.setUserId(props.userId)
      }
    
}

const KittenLayer = createLayerComponent(createKittenLayer, updateKittenLayer);
export default KittenLayer;
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to create a custom component in `react-leaflet v3`.  If you're not super familiar with react-leaflet, this might be daunting.  The docs on writing a custom component are a little hard to follow.  I found this section helpful: [Element hook factory](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-architecture#element-hook-factory)

So you need to start with 2 basic functions.  One function to create your element, and one to update it.  To create it,

```js
// Assuming you've already defined L.TileLayer.WebGis somewhere
// and attached it to the global L

const createWebGisLayer = (props, context) => {

  const instance = L.tileLayer.webGis(props.url, {...props})

  return { instance, context }

}
```

Then you need another function that will handle any updates you want to trickle down into your component. For example, if a certain prop of your component changes, you need to explicitly tell react-leaflet to update the underlying leaflet instance of that component:

```js
const updateWebGisLayer = (instance, props, prevProps) => {

  if (prevProps.url !== props.url) {
    if (instance.setUrl) instance.setUrl(props.url)
  }

  if (prevProps.userId !== props.userId) {
    if (instance.setUserId) instance.setUserId(props.userId)
  }

}
```

You need these setter functions to tell react-leaflet that if the `url` or `userId` (or whatever) prop changes in react, it needs to rerender the leaflet layer.  `setUrl` already exists on `L.TileLayer`, but you'll need to define a `setUserId` that updated the `userId` option of the `L.TileLayer.WebGis` instance.  If you don't include these, your component will not update when its props changes.

To put it all together, you can use the [`createLayerComponent`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api#createlayercomponent) factory function:

```js
const WebGisLayer = createLayerComponent(createWebGisLayer, updateWebGisLayer)
export WebGisLayer
```

`WebGisLayer` is now a react component that you can use as a child of a `MapContainer`

```js
const App = () => {

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('user123')

  return (
    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
      <WebGisLayer 
        url="some_url" 
        userId={userId}
        otherPropsYouNeed={otherProps} />
    </MapContainer>
  )

}
```

When the component loads it will run your leaflet code and add the leaflet component to the map.  If the `userId` changes due to some setstate call, your `updateWebGisLayer` function tells react-leaflet to update the underlying leaflet component.

There's a lot of ways to do this, but this is the one I think is most straightforward.  I haven't had a chance to test this code so you'll inevitably have to play around with it to get it working, but this should get you started.

Comment: Tried following the steps mentioned here. I'm unable to render my custom component and am getting the error `No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>`. Am I doing something wrong or did I miss any imports for it to work. I'm using `react-leaflet ^3.2.0` and `leaflet ^1.7.1`

Comment: I'd have to see the code to know what the issue is.  Are you sure your custom component is being used as a child of the MapContainer?

Comment: Ya. I'm using it as a child component of mapp container. Let me see if I can put a stackblitz link of this.

Comment: I was getting that error because of using `@react-leaflet/core ^1.0.2`. Uggrading the version to `@react-leaflet/core ^1.1.0` fixed it. Thanks for your help. Figured this issue out when setting up the stackblitz link.