Correct way to extend leaflet classes with TypeScript
I am trying to extend the Marker class in leaflet.
I have read the tutorial on extending the class system and have managed to extend Marker with my desired functionality. However, I am unable to get everything working with no TypeScript errors.
I have my marker
const PhysicalSizeMarker = L.Marker.extend({ options: { width: 0, height: 0, }, ... }) 

and I have my factory as recommended by the tutorial
export function physicalSizeMarker(
  latlng: L.LatLngExpression,
  options: PhysicalSizeMarkerOptions,
) {
  return new PhysicalSizeMarker(latlng, options);
}

But the constructor of the factory has a type error:
Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.

I can make these errors go away by extending the Marker class in the usual JavaScript way and this seems to keep my added functionality working:
class PhysicalSizeMarker extends L.Marker {
  constructor(latlng: L.LatLngExpression, options: PhysicalSizeMarkerOptions) {
    super(latlng, options);
  }

This approach was recommended in this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692385/11451589
However, the leaflet documentation specifically says not to do that and instead use .extend
Does anyone know the correct approach to extending leaflet classes, such as markers, with TypeScript

When creating a class using the extend method, the constructor signature appears to be be unknown to TypeScript's type checking.
You could bypass TypeScript's type checking by doing something like this:
export function physicalSizeMarker(
    latlng: L.LatLngExpression, options: PhysicalSizeMarkerOptions) {

  return new (PhysicalSizeMarker as any)(latlng, options) as PhysicalSizeMarker;

}

I wrote an example here.
However, if there are better ways to do this, I would also be interested in knowing how.
