# updating props when using createControlComponent in react-leaflet 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

Following the offical reference for [Higher Level Component Factory](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-architecture#higher-level-component-factory) to update props for a Control Component

> The core APIs export other [high-level component factories](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api#high-level-component-factories) that can be
> used in a similar way.

I've mimicked the example - but I get a syntax error for the following:

```js
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
import { createControlComponent } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import 'leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css'

function setWaypoints(props)
{
    return { 
        waypoints: [
        L.latLng(props.startLat, props.startLng),
        L.latLng(props.endLat, props.endLng)
        ],
        lineOptions: {
            styles: [{ color: "#0500EE", weight: 4 }]
        },
        show: false,
        addWaypoints: false,
        routeWhileDragging: true,
        draggableWaypoints: true,
        fitSelectedRoutes: true,
        showAlternatives: false,
        createMarker: function() { return null; },

    }
}


function createRoutingMachine(props, context) 
{
    const instance =  new L.Routing.control(setWaypoints(props))
    return 
    { 
        instance, context: { ...context, overlayContainer: instance }    
    }
}


function updateRoutingMachine(instance, props, prevProps)
{
    if (props.endLat !== prevProps.endLat || props.endLng !== prevProps.endLng) 
    {
        instance.setWaypoints(props)
    }
}

const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(createRoutingMachine, updateRoutingMachine)
export default RoutingMachine;
```

> Missing semicolon. (35:25)
>
> 33 |     return    34 |     {
>
> > 35 |         instance, context: { ...context, overlayContainer: instance }
> > |                          ^   36 |     }

If I change this to:

```js
function createRoutingMachine(props) 
{
    const instance =  new L.Routing.control(setWaypoints(props))
    return instance
}
```

The compiler is happy, but the component never updates.

I know I'm creating the Control Component incorrectly, but I can't find the information for the correct implementation.

Related:
[How to use Leaflet Routing Machine with React-Leaflet 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658340/how-to-use-leaflet-routing-machine-with-react-leaflet-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[How to extend TileLayer component in react-leaflet v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663826/how-to-extend-tilelayer-component-in-react-leaflet-v3/65713838#65713838)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will notice that in the docs, [`createcontrolcomponent`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#createcontrolcomponent) lists only one argument, which is a function to create the instance. You are expecting it to behave like [`createlayercomponent`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#createlayercomponent), which takes two arguments.  In createlayercomponent, the second argument is a function to update the layer component when the props change.  However, `createcontrolcomponent` offers no such functionality.  react-leaflet is assuming, much like vanilla leaflet, that once your control is added to the map, you won't need to alter it directly.

This gets a bit confusing in terms of leaflet-routing-machine, because you don't need to change the instance of the control, but rather you need to call a method on it which affects the map presentation.

IMO, the best way to go is to use a state variable to keep track of whether or not your waypoints have changed, and use a ref to access the underlying leaflet instance of the routing machine, and call `setWayPoints` on that:

```js
// RoutineMachine.jsx

const createRoutineMachineLayer = (props) => {
  const { waypoints } = props;
  const instance = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints,
    ...otherOptions
  });

  return instance;
};

// Takes only 1 argument:
const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(createRoutineMachineLayer);
```

```js
// Map.jsx

const Map = (props) => {
  // create a ref
  const rMachine = useRef();
  // create some state variable, any state variable, to track changes
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(true);
  const pointsToUse = points ? points1 : points2;

  // useEffect which responds to changes in waypoints state variable
  useEffect(() => {
    if (rMachine.current) {
      rMachine.current.setWaypoints(pointsToUse);
    }
  }, [pointsToUse, rMachine]);

  return (
    <MapContainer {...props}>
      <RoutineMachine ref={rMachine} waypoints={pointsToUse} />
      <button onClick={() => setPoints(!points)}>
        Toggle Points State and Props
      </button>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlv3-routing-machine-w-props-yfdk1)

Bonus: a cheap and easy way to force a rerender on your `<RoutineMachine>` component (or any react component) is to assign it a `key` prop, and change that key prop when you want to rerender it.  This might be a uuid, or even a unique set of waypoints ran through JSON.stringify. Just an idea.

Comment: This just saved me hours of debugging. It worked out of the box

Comment: Nice pointer - in my case some of the props on `react-leaflet` Locate control need changing dynamically so I had to retain a ref as suggested