# React leaflet display simple route

Tags: reactjs, routes, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I want to display a route between 2 or more coordinates. I don't want any fancy direction instructions or start and end markers. So basically something like a `<Polyline />` that goes along roads. I know there is a leaflet-routing-machine, but I wasn't able to make it work using React and Typescript.
[image: Like this]

What is the best way to do that?

---

Edit: I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67661225/17907378) but I don't know how to edit the `L.Routing.Itinerary` properties which I need to edit to disable the directions instructions and the Marker style.
[image: Like this]

Comment: Could you include your code so far?

Comment: I only have the basic `<MapContainer>` and i only display a map without any routes or markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add two things to achieve that behavior:

1.According to the [maintainer](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/20#issuecomment-133302168) add this to make routing panel dissapear on styles.css.

```
.leaflet-control-container .leaflet-routing-container-hide {
     display: none;
}
```

2.Add this to make markers dissapear when you create the routing control instance

```
createMarker: function () {
      return null;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v-3-display-simple-route-using-leaflet-routing-machine-gwjod0)

Comment: I had to use `.leaflet-control-container { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

to disable the directions just set show = false in the control options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with the help of supporting information, such as citations or documentation

Comment: I'm sorry, here's a page with some alternatives:
https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/608

Specific answer from the creator:
https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/20#issuecomment-51523806

As a said before, defining " show = false " worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this one in react typescript (show:false to disable table, and for marker : createMarker: function () {
return null;
} ),

the issue im facing is the number of waypoints, it works for a certain number of points, after which the route disappears. and also the map freezes on large number of waypoints